# How to set a fixed frame for a label?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uilabel

I have a custom cell with 2 textfields and in view for header in section I'm taking a view and displaying two labels at x positions 5 and 180. at 180 the position of view changes everytime i change the device. i want the 2 nd label frame to just above the 2nd textfield. how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken the x position of label2 regarding the width of label1, which worked for me.

The code is:

```
label2.frame = CGRectMake(label1.frame.size.width+30, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: If you found the solution, you can mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can set second textfields frame as :

```
int margin = 5;
UITextField *txtFieldSecond = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, CGRectGetMaxY(txtFieldOne.frame)+margin, width, height)];
```

Comment: Thanks but i need label frame

Comment: Yes you can use the same format for label also as :\t

UILabel *lblFieldSecond = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, CGRectGetMaxY(txtFieldOne.frame)+margin, width, height)];